# Create rectangle and display on new form

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

So I'm trying to create a new form, draw a rectangle and then have that rectangle shown on the form. I can't seem to get it to show. The form shows but the rectangle isnt drawn.

I have this so far:

```
private void btnLayout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.Text = "Design";
    using (Graphics g = form.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.AliceBlue);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, 100, 100, 200);
        pen.Dispose();
    }
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: How big is the form? Is it higher than 100px and wider than 100px?

Comment: Fixed it, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should paint on your form in [`Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the form, otherwise your painting will be disappear if something make your form repaint, for example a minimize and restore or moving another window above your window.

**Example**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Form();
    f.Paint += (se, pe) =>
    {
        var r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
        pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, r);
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
    };
    f.Show();
}
```

**Note**

- You can use `Brushes.AliceBlue` instead of `new SolidBrush(Color.AliceBlue)`
- If in any reason you created a new `SolidBrush`, don't forget to dispose it.
- Create and use disposable objects in a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) block. This way they automatically will dispose after they went out of scope at the end of using.
- The statement `f.Paint += (se, pe) =>{/*...*/}` is equivalent to
  `f.Paint += f_Paint;` and then having such method `void f_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {/*...*/}` .

Comment: Hi, you were right in your comment. But in regards to my code, wouldn't the brush be disposed due to the fact that it's already in a using statement? Wont it already only exist in the using block? Although can you explain the f.Paint += in another way. Im not sure I understand. Doesn't that add a new paint instance?

Comment: `f.Paint += (se, pe) =>{/*...*/}` is a way to assign a delegate to an event as event handler.  It's equivalent to `f.Paint += f_Paint;` and then having such method `void f_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {/*...*/} `. For an example see [Use Lambda Expressions Outside LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383984.aspx).

Comment: When you create a using block: `using (var x= new X()){ /*...*/}` then `x` is guaranteed to be disposed after end of block. The using doesn't have any impact on other objects in the block. For more information see [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I understand. So is the paint method persistent?

Comment: Yes, every time when the paint event raises, that inline method or event handler will execute and run paint logic. Always do painting in `Paint` event handler.

Comment: But you cannot access them from outside the using block? So why wouldn't they be disposed?

Comment: Yes you can not access outside the block because of scope. Disposing is completely different. For example when you define a brush in a method, while you can not access it outside of method, but if you don't dispose it, it will not dispose. The same rule exists for a block.

Comment: I did upvote you, I had less than 15 rep and it wouldn't let me but I just got 19 so I upvoted you. Thank you

Comment: Thank reza, got it

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I couldn't add a rectangle on a form that wasn't shown yet but it works if you put the code after the form has been shown.

```
private void btnLayout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form form = new Form();

            form.Text = "Design";

            form.Show();

            using (Graphics g = form.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.AliceBlue);

                g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, 100, 100, 200);

                pen.Dispose();
            }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to draw a rectangle on your form. To see the problem, just minimize your form and restore it again and see the result. I posted an answer for you containing some useful notes :)

Answer (score 0):

Show the form, then draw the rectangle.

ie:  move the `form.Show()` call above:

```
using (Graphics g = form.CreateGraphics())
```